# Parse complex JSON In flutter and type 'Future<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Future<AllUsers>'

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm just parsing complex JSON and display on listView for learning purpose.

> **API:**  https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users

**1) Model Class**

```html
class AllUsers {
  final List<User> alluser;

  AllUsers({this.alluser});

  factory AllUsers.formJson(List<dynamic> jsonArr){
    List<User> arruser = jsonArr.map((f)=> User.formJson(f)).toList();
    return AllUsers(
      alluser:  arruser
    );
  }
}
class User {
  int id;
  String name;
  String email;
  Address address;
  String phone;
  String website;
  Company company;

  User({this.id, this.name, this.email, this.address, this.phone, this.website, this.company});

  factory User.formJson(Map<String, dynamic> jsonObj) {
    return User(
      id: jsonObj['id'],
      name: jsonObj['name'],
      email: jsonObj['email'],
      address: Address.formJson(jsonObj['address']),
      phone: jsonObj['phone'],
      website: jsonObj['website'],
      company: Company.formJson(jsonObj['company'])
    );
  }
} 
class Address {
  String street;
  String suite;
  String city;
  String zipcode;
  Geo geo;

  Address({this.street, this.suite, this.city, this.zipcode, this.geo});

  factory Address.formJson(Map<String, dynamic> jsonObj) {
    return Address(
      street: jsonObj['street'],
      suite: jsonObj['suite'],
      city: jsonObj['city'],
      zipcode: jsonObj['zipcode'],
      geo: Geo.formJson(jsonObj['geo'])
    );
  }
} 
class Geo {
  String lat;
  String lng;

  Geo({this.lat, this.lng});

  factory Geo.formJson(Map<String, dynamic> jsonObj) {
    return Geo(
      lat: jsonObj['lat'],
      lng: jsonObj['lng'],
    );
  }
} 
class Company {
  String name;
  String catchPhrase;
  String bs;

  Company({this.name, this.catchPhrase, this.bs});

  factory Company.formJson(Map<String, dynamic> jsonObj) {
    return Company(
      name: jsonObj['name'],
      catchPhrase: jsonObj['catchPhrase'],
      bs: jsonObj['bs']
    );
  }
}
```

**2)ViewModel**

```
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:parsejsonlist/All Screens/Home/Model/users.dart';

class UserViewModel {
  Future<AllUsers> callWebserviceForFetchUserData() async{
    var listOfUser = await http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users');
    List<User> decodedJSON = json.decode(listOfUser.body);
    AllUsers arrayOfAlluser = AllUsers.formJson(decodedJSON);
    print("arrayOfAlluser $arrayOfAlluser");
    return arrayOfAlluser;
  }
}
```

**3) View Portion of the code.**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:parsejsonlist/All Screens/Home/Model/users.dart';
import 'package:parsejsonlist/All Screens/Home/ModelView/userviewmodel.dart';

class HomeSceen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => HomeScreenState();
}

class HomeScreenState extends State<HomeSceen> {

  AllUsers arryOfUser;
  UserViewModel userViewmodel;

  @override 
  initState(){
    super.initState();     
    userViewmodel = UserViewModel();
  }

  callMethodFetchUserData() async {
    arryOfUser = await userViewmodel.callWebserviceForFetchUserData();
    User userRes =  arryOfUser.alluser[0];
    print("response === >> ${userRes.company.catchPhrase}");
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("JSON Parsing")
      ),
      body: Container(
        child: FutureBuilder<AllUsers>(
          future: callMethodFetchUserData(),
          builder: (context, data){
            return setupListView();
          },          
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget setupListView(){
  return ListView.builder(
    itemCount: arryOfUser.alluser.length,
    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
      User userdata = arryOfUser.alluser[index];
      setupListTile(userdata);
    },
  );
 }



    Widget setupListTile(User userdata){
  return ListTile(
    leading: CircleAvatar(
      backgroundColor: Colors.orangeAccent,
      child: Text(userdata.name[0].toUpperCase(), 
      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
    ),
    title: Text(userdata.name),
    subtitle: Text(userdata.company.name),    
  );
 }
}
```

So, My question is each time i'm getting fail with so many error like.

> type 'Future' is not a subtype of type 'Future'

I know there are so many mistake but I'm new to Flutter.
Where i'm going wrong? How to solve this issue please guide me on right direction.

**UPDATED**

```
child: FutureBuilder<List<User>>(
          future: userViewmodel.callWebserviceForFetchUserData(),
          builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<List<User>> snapshot) {
            switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
              case ConnectionState.none:
                return Text('Press button to start.');
              case ConnectionState.active:
              case ConnectionState.waiting:
                return Text('Awaiting result...');
              case ConnectionState.done:
                if (snapshot.hasError) return Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}');
                return setupListView(snapshot.data);
            }
            return null;
          },

Getting Error: "Type List<dynamic> is not a subtype of type List<User>"
```

[image]

Is there any mistake in model class ?

Comment: These lines look suspicious: `List<User> decodedJSON = json.decode(listOfUser.body); AllUsers arrayOfAlluser = AllUsers.formJson(decodedJSON);` Are you sure you have the types of those expressions correct? I would just use `var` for both

Comment: Actually I don't know exactly. I wrote code as per my understanding so used var as You told but same issue occurs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Throw away the `AllUsers` type, and the `arryOfUser` member. You don't need them, and by putting them in, you haven't matched the expectation of FutureBuilder.

```
class UserViewModel {
  Future<List<User>> fetchUserData() async {
    var response = await http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users');
    List<User> users = json.decode(response.body).map((u) => User.formJson(u)).toList();
    print("users $users");
    print("response === >> ${users[0].company.catchPhrase}");
    return users;
  }
}

class HomeScreenState extends State<HomeSceen> {

  UserViewModel userViewmodel;

  @override 
  initState(){
    super.initState();     
    userViewmodel = UserViewModel();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("JSON Parsing")
      ),
      body: Container(
        child: FutureBuilder<List<User>>(
          future: userViewmodel.fetchUserData(), 
          builder: (context, snap){
            return setupListView(snap.data);
          },          
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget setupListView(List<User> users){
  return ListView.builder(
    itemCount: users.length,
    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
      setupListTile(users[index]);
    },
  );
 }

 Widget setupListTile(User userdata){
  return ListTile(
    leading: CircleAvatar(
      backgroundColor: Colors.orangeAccent,
      child: Text(userdata.name[0].toUpperCase(), 
      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
    ),
    title: Text(userdata.name),
    subtitle: Text(userdata.company.name),    
  );
 }
}
```

Comment: 'AsyncSnapshot<List<User>>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'List<User>' at return setupListView(data); in FutureBuilder

Comment: @Govaadiyo see edit. This is me guessing Flutter and googling for the typenames in your errors

Comment: flutter: The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building FutureBuilder<List<User>>(dirty, state:
flutter: _FutureBuilderState<List<User>>#30a18):
flutter: The getter 'length' was called on null.
flutter: Receiver: null
flutter: Tried calling: length

Comment: @Govaadiyo you probably want to look at [this](https://medium.com/@jimmyhott/using-futurebuilder-to-create-a-better-widget-4c7d4f52a329) too

Comment: Ok thanks for tutorial It will increase my knowledge. If any help require then I will comment you.. Thanks for support.

Comment: Don't know but after close the VC Code as well as simulator and run again it works.